# Laravel 5 Routing

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing, laravel-5, laravel-routing

As a beginner at Laravel 5 programming i am trying to develop a basic application in order to learn Laravel 5 fundamentals. In my application, i have a couple of pages and i am trying to route them as:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/vehicles', 'PagesController@vehiclepage');
Route::get('/calculation', 'PagesController@calculationpage');
Route::get('/settings', 'PagesController@settingspage');
```

PagesController:

```
class PagesController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
            return view('index');
    }

        public function vehiclepage()
    {
            return view('vehiclepage');
    }

        public function calculationpage()
    {
            return view('calculationpage');
    }

        public function settingspage()
    {
            return view('settingspage');
    }
}
```

Some form process will be goin on in these pages ass well. I wonder, is there a more efficient way to have a better routing for my pages ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? For a basic static site, your routing is fine.

Comment: @Joe as a beginner just wonderig is there a better way or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st of all if you want to access those pages at main route at your site as :  /{pagename}  the best way is to stay as you have it.. list them all 1 by 1. Its not good to have dynamic matching router for the main site route "/".

If its ok for you to set some prefix to this route as: '/page/{pagename}' here is a nice dynamic loader..

```
class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function show( $slug)
    {
        $pageslug = 'page.' . (string)$slug; 
        // This means that your views must be in views/page/ folder
        if( view()->exists($pageslug)){
            return view($pageslug);
        }
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

And your route will be:

```
Route::get('/page/{slug}', 'PagesController@show');
```

At end all views in views/page/XXXX will be accessible at /page/{viewname}

Comment: `Its not good to have dynamic matching router for the main site route "/".` Just wondering, since I've heard this many times - why not? As long as you define that route _after_ all others so it doesn't end up a catch-all it should work and remain understandable.

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov I wouldn't consider it not good in every case. It is a big problem if the dynamic content is defined by the user (like a username). Otherwise there shouldn't be a problem. Just as you say: define it after all other routes

Comment: The problem with dynamic routing at main "/" is that your router will always match requests instead to go to 404 without starting anything..
And if you are not careful and you put anything after this route it will be lost..
There are many reasons why not .. 
And there is no reason why you should have it.. some people make it for seo but this is not a real optimisation .. /{username} is the only thing where I can agree to add it

Comment: 1. A "Controller method not found" exception raised by Laravel still returns an HTTP 404 status code, and the cost of having to look up a nonexistent route is negligible, all other things happening in the framework considered. Also, asking for an undefined route [still "starts" a lot of stuff](http://pastebin.com/veW1PSN3). 2. I explicitly stated that such a route should go after any others, and of course you have to be careful when coding. 3. I completely didn't get the /{username} part. Let's not abuse comments though, I respect your point :)

Comment: Controller method not found its not possible if you have copy both codes (controller and router)

Comment: @Svetlio what do you mean by 'put anything after this route it will be lost' ? Dont get why i should not use dynamic routing.

Comment: @Tartar have a look at my answer to the question, specifically the `routes.php` file. He means that if you "reverse" the two lines, you will never be able to get to 'http://your.domain/login` unless your `getLogin` method is in `WelcomeController`.

Answer (score 2):

Your routing is perfectly fine, although there are alternatives. For example, you may define your routing like so:

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('login', ['uses' => 'LoginController@index']);
Route::controller('/', 'WelcomeController');
```

**WelcomeController.php**

```
class PagesController extends Controller {

public function getIndex()
{
    return view('homepage');
}

public function getVehicle()
{
    return view('vehiclepage');
}

public function getCalculation()
{
    return view('calculationpage');
}

public function getSettings()
{
    return view('settingspage');
}

}
```

What this will do is route GET requests to your.domain/login to the `index` method of your `LoginController` (assuming you will have one), and if the parameter is anything else, it will try to find a method that starts with `get` and ends with the word being requested, in the `PagesController`, then serve it, so a GET request to your.domain/settings will end up in the `getSettings` method of `PagesController`. You can read more about how this all works [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers)

Note - I'm not saying that this method is *better* - some people say that "monolithic" routers are the Devil, while others (like me) prefer to have all the logic in the controller and have the routing defined in the most condensed way possible. It all comes down to personal preference and style. Just keep in mind that consistency is key - whichever approach you prefer, stick to it!

Answer (score 1):

I had same question, because I was coming from KOHANA FW and then I did in my Laravel project like this :

```
 Route::get('/{controller?}/{action?}/{id?}', function ($controller='Home', $action='defaulmethod', $id = null) {
    $controller = ucfirst($controller);
    return APP::make("{$controller}Controller")->$action($id);
});
```

It worked when url was like this :

```
/{Controller}/{action}/{id}
```

but i think your route system is not bad, it is very easy to understand and if you don't make big project - you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Route::get('{page}', function($page) {
        return View::make($page);
});
```

Comment: You were possibly downvoted because you haven't explained your answer in any detail. It will be more helpful to the OP and to future readers if you could add some clarification to what your answer does/why it works :)

Comment: Thank you for comment , that i will try to improve my answer :) @JamesHay

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to laravel also, I think you made the things in the right way. But just a small advice, try to keep your code very clean for your future use, like that :

```
class PagesController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
            return view('index');
    }

    public function vehiclepage()
    {
            return view('vehiclepage');
    }

    public function calculationpage()
    {
            return view('calculationpage');
    }

    public function settingspage()
    {
            return view('settingspage');
    }
}
```

As the public function vehiclepage is new function and it is not a part of the public function index.

Comment: i see no difference between your code and mine. What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do route-model binding (google it) that you can ignore using wildcards such as

```
pagename/{id}
```

you can use `Route::resource()` see: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

The implicit controller routes may be fine for you if u wish,as said by Kaloyan Doichinov.
your route.php file will be like
Route::controller('/','yourControllerName');

and ur controller method should be prepand with http verb,like
eg index() =>  getIndex(){} etc

so for post request use => postMethodName(){}     //change MethodName with ur method name.

and so on for put,delete etc requests.......